# How to refer resource files from dependent jar in gradle task?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to use resource file from dependent jar to generate code/POJO. Maven has maven-remote-resources-plugin. I didn't find any equivalent gradle plugin. Also not sure if gradle has any default task for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to use my custom lib with Gradle:

- Copy your JAR file to your module ‘libs’ folder. If you don’t have ‘libs’ folder then create one.
- Add the library to your ‘module’ Gradle dependencies

dependencies:

```
dependencies {   
     compile files('libs/your-library-file-name.jar') 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. let me try this approach. Also, did you used any gradle task to copy jar to lib or doing manual copy?